# resizing fixed table headers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with `width=100%`, with many rows and with fixed headers.
The fixed headers solution I got from this side: [Persistent Headers](https://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/)

```js
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
  $(".persist-area").each(function() {
    var el = $(this),
      offset = el.offset(),
      scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
      floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

    if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
      floatingHeader.css({
        "visibility": "visible"
      });
    } else {
      floatingHeader.css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
      });
    };
  });
}

$(function() {
  var $floatingHeader = $(".persist-header", this).clone();

  $floatingHeader.children().width(function(i, val) {
    return $(".persist-header").children().eq(i).width();
  });

  $floatingHeader.css("width", $(".persist-header", this).width()).addClass("floatingHeader");
  $(".persist-header", this).before($floatingHeader);

  $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");
});
```

```css
.floatingHeader {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="100%" class="persist-area">
  <tr class="persist-header">
    <th> Entry 1</th>
    <th> Entry 2</th>
  </tr>
  <!-- stuff and stuff -->
</table>
```

And now, if I open my page, everything looks fine.
Even after scrolling the new fixed header appears.
But if I resize the page (e.g. sizing the window to half the width) the fixed header keeps its original size.

I think the problem lies within the `return $(".persist-header").children().eq(i).width();` part. It seems as if it creates the header with a fixed pixel width and not a percentage one.

How can I achieve a fixed header with auto-sizing width?

Comment: I believe .width() always returns a pixel value. Perhaps .css(width) would work? If not, you'd have to manually calculate the percentage based on the return value of .width().

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
      //...
});
```

And rerun your header width code in there

Comment: I placed it in `$(function() {` but it's not working: 
`$(window).resize(function() {
        var $floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this);
        $floatingHeader.children().width(function (i, val) {
          return $(".persist-header").children().eq(i).width();
        });
      });`